# Generating Firebase Auth Tokens in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, firebase, firebase-security

I'm trying to set up some simple security rules for my Firebase (essentially, any authorized user can read/write), which I'm using with a Rails application that uses Devise for user-authentication. However, I'm having trouble understanding how the process of generating tokens work.

I found the Ruby gem here:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-ruby

However, I'm not sure where I'm supposed to put this snippet of Ruby code:

```
require "firebase_token_generator"

arbitraryAuthPayload = {:auth_data => "foo", :other_auth_data => "bar"}

generator = Firebase::FirebaseTokenGenerator.new("<YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>")
token = generator.create_token(arbitraryAuthPayload)
```

Do I just put it in an initializer along with a variable for user_id?

Also, I saw that tokens expire after 24 hours. Does that mean this token generator will automatically generate a new token for each client with an expired token?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to structure ruby code. Isn't that entirely in the purview of your particular conundrum of philosophy? Put it wherever you want to create the tokens. I don't think without knowing your app in full we can offer advice here. Regarding the expiry: it's your job to renew them; there is no automagically; check out [.info/authenticated and presence management](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html) for some help here.

Comment: Hmm, so if I'm using Devise, then it should generate a token everytime a user logs in with Devise right? Does that mean it should go in a Devise file?

Comment: Do the clients connect to Firebase directly? Or are the reads / writes through the ruby backend?

Comment: It's actually both. I have one or two writes that are initiated through a model, but the rest are on the client side. Basically, I just want to make sure that not any random person with my firebase url can read/write data (since it's exposed right in the views), as that could really screw things up (and there's also sensitive info like location data that i'm streaming). I know that there's only so much that can be done to mitigate this, but at least only accepting read/write requests from signed in users (via Devise) might go a long way...unless there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 2):

If the clients need to read/write from Firebase directly they will need to have that token to auth to Firebase before they can, so it would probably be a good idea to generate a token wherever you're handling user authentication / initialization.

As you mentioned, the default session length is 24 hours, so after that they will need a new token. You can specify a different expiry time using a second options parameter with an `:expires` key to the `create_token` method as mentioned in the README to any future date. That way you can set it for say 30 days in the future, or whatever your normal session length is, or you could create an endpoint that returns a valid token and handle the expiration gracefully on the frontend.

If the ruby server is the only thing accessing Firebase, things are a little easier - you could just create a server token once and allow it read/write access to the whole Firebase